# Finding keywords and does not include where the keyword string shows up only as a part of a larger word

Tags: python, keyword

I cleaned the text but dont really understand how to not include the words that is a part of a larger word. for example if i look for closed doesnt show enclosed

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    indices=[]
    for i,j in enumerate(doc_list):
        text = j.split()
        for t in text:
            clean = t.rstrip('.,!\'\\').lower()
        if keyword.lower() in clean:
            indices.append(i)
            
    return indices
```

Comment: show what your problem is and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

You probably want strict equality, `keyword.lower() == clean`, *not* inclusion (`keyword.lower() in clean`).

Answer (score 0):

I changed this part

```
for t in text:
            clean = t.rstrip('.,!\'\\').lower()
```

to this

```
clean = [t.rstrip('.,!\'\\').lower() for t in text]
```

And it worked, But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted .If not then let me know

```
x = ['nn', 'anna', 'ara', 'cec', 'aceca', 'racecar', 'mom']
x.sort(key = len, reverse = True)
output = []
for ele in x:
    for ele2 in x[x.index(ele):]:
        if all(item in ele for item in ele2):
            x.remove(ele2)
            if ele not in output:
                output.append(ele)
print(output)
```

**Output**
['racecar', 'mom']

I thinks This code can be improved .If yes please suggest the necessary edits.